# Swapping each pair of values in a multimap<int, int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, swap, multimap

I have a multimap containing over 5 million pairs and I need to swap the keys with the values.

```
unordered_multimap<int, int> edge;
```

Due to the large size of the container and the processes involved, I would prefer to not have to create a new multimap with the swapped pairs by iterating over each element of the map.

What would be the best way, if any, to do this *in place*?

Comment: _Why_ do you "need" to do this? Surely a bimap makes more sense if you need to do lookup in the other direction occasionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper approach is *not to do this at all*, but instead to have a bi-directional map in the first place, on which you can perform lookup in either direction.

Consider looking into [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this in-place.

The map you have stored the elements based of the hash values of its key. If you want to hash on a different key (the former value) you have to rebuild the whole map or think of a different way to store the elements.

[Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) (as suggested by Lightness Races in Orbit) for example supports bidirectional unordered multimaps.